# Saving a high score and updating it as score increases

Tags: unity, c#, scoring

I'm following Brackeys *"Dodge the Blocks"* tutorial. In the video, he covered everything accept the score/high score system.

I have a working score system, which gives you 1 point every time you collect a coin.

In the scene where you play the game, I have a text UI that says "Score:", and another one for the score number, another that says "Best:", and one more for the best number.

I want to make it so that your high score gets **saved**, and **updates in real-time with your score every time you pass the score**.

Here are some of the scripts:

UI Manager (Where I want to put the high score code):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text scoreText;
    int score;

    public static int coinAmount;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
    CoinTextScript.coinAmount += 1;
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    public void scoreUpdate()
    {
        score++;
    }
}
```

Coin Text Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinTextScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Text text;
    Text bestScoreText;
    public static int coinAmount;
    public int score;

    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text> ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        text.text = coinAmount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you already consulted [existing Q&A about adding a high score to a Unity game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=high+score+%5Bunity%5D)? Can you show us how you've tried to track, update, and store your high score variable based on this research?

Comment: Well, I really don't know to be honest, because I am very new to coding and Unity, sorry. I know I have tried many things though. I know I am really being a pain right now but I have tried so many things that I really don't know. I just want someone to write the script for me at this point because yes, I've consulted many forum pages, watched 50+ YouTube tutorials, etc. It's not like I just haven't tried and am asking for someone to do it for me like that. But if you or someone you know are willing to help me how I asking, it would be greatly appreciated sir/ma'am.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add high score?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164016/how-to-add-high-score)